# Html and Css coding required for banner ads placement

Tags: html, css

I need help to place banner ads in my website as per given format.

[Required Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35xk.jpg)

I'm using a ready script for my website.
I got the advertisement codes from the ad networks already.
And I placed those codes to my index.php file. Please see what it looks (existing format).

[Existing format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGbCK.jpg)

In existing format, 250x250 banner size is not available but I will generate it from the ad network later and place it to the required format.

Also there is a problem while displaying existing format in different size screens. In a bigger screen the banners shows in a line, while in small screen it shows as per the provided photo.

Please note, the coding should be "inline style" because I cannot do any editing in "external or internal style sheet".

I just put the below codes exactly the same into the index.php file. And the look is as per the given photo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/xx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/xx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/xx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/xx"></script>
```

I will be very much grateful to get help from you.

B. regards

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? You should post the code you have thus far, welcome to SO!

Comment: Please note this is not a code writing service. We expect you to provide a clear statement of problem, errors, pertinent code, and what you have tried to solve this. If you just need code google "freelance code service"

Comment: @Omarjmh 
I have edited the post. Please check the codes I've placed into the index.php file. I have tried many ways to do the thing perfectly by searching in google. But it seems I didn't met my requirement.

Comment: @scrappedcola
I tried many ways to solve my problem by my own. And after that I came here to seek help. And I cannot afford to hire freelancer to my job done.

Comment: What inline styles have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- named just for fun -->
<advertisementbox style="position:relative;">
<a href="the link to go to"><img style="width:250px;height:250px;position:absolute;top:0;" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKFg5QbQ7HLt4IyvBzVZfO6AZ4Cfx7XIOOHygfDzqRZTZtJ9DKA"></a><a href="the link to go to"><img style="width:468px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:0;left:255px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKFg5QbQ7HLt4IyvBzVZfO6AZ4Cfx7XIOOHygfDzqRZTZtJ9DKA"></a><a href="the link to go to"><img style="width:468px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:95;left:255px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKFg5QbQ7HLt4IyvBzVZfO6AZ4Cfx7XIOOHygfDzqRZTZtJ9DKA"></a><a href="the link to go to"><img style="width:468px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:190;left:255px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKFg5QbQ7HLt4IyvBzVZfO6AZ4Cfx7XIOOHygfDzqRZTZtJ9DKA"></a><a href="the link to go to"><img style="width:250px;height:250px;position:absolute;top:0;left:728;" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKFg5QbQ7HLt4IyvBzVZfO6AZ4Cfx7XIOOHygfDzqRZTZtJ9DKA"></a>

</advertisementbox>
```

i hope this helps!

if it doesn't let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your kind interest to help me.

I have a question, 
Where should I place this code in your given code. It looks different than the codes I received from the Ad Networks. 

AD NETWORK CODE:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/xx"></script>

YOUR GIVEN CODE:
<a href="#"><img style="width:468px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:0;left:255px;" src="#"></a>

Comment: are there specific id srcs that need to be changed?

Comment: FIRST:
I tried your given code by putting all the Href Links  and Img Src Links. But It didn't worked. All the banners are unorganized. 

SECOND:
If you can give me a solution for the above problem then please tell me about the ad networks link <script type="text/javascript" src="adhitzads.com/xx"></script>. Where I should put it in your <a href="#"><img style="width:468px;height:60px;position:absolute;top:0;left:255px;" src="#"></a> 

THIRD:
I can't give you an answer about the ID SRCS. I don't have much knowledge about programming. If you tell me the code then I will just copy paste it.